# How to send messages as "important" with gmailr?

Tags: r, gmail, gmail-api

Is it possible to mark messages as "important" with `gmailr`?

Comment: The person sending the email doesn't get to control if the email will be marked important in the recipient's mailbox.  Or did I misunderstand what you're asking?

Comment: The Gmail receiver is in a position to set the markers for important emails but not the sender.

Comment: thank you, that answers my question